# Popup control not staying open on action

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the ajaxtoolkit in order to make a popup where users can interact with server controls. Here is a simple implemetation:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

<ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server"
     TargetControlID="Button1"
     PopupControlID="Panel1"
     Position="Center" />

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="AppName" DataValueField="PK_Application"></asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [AppName], [PK_Application] FROM [Application]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
```

It appears to be working correctly, but when I press the button the panel flashes open then dissapears and I can't interact with it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to prevent the postback of the button click:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;"); 
}
```